# A mix of affix riddles

Tags: riddle, knowledge, affix-riddle

Firstly:

> My prefix is something located behind,
> My suffix a place I go with worry on my mind.

Secondly:

> My prefix is wind, albeit reversed and then headless,
> My suffix noble, and helps to be soundless.

Thirdly:

> My prefix rises quickly, when adding numbers to its core,
> My suffix a goodbye, used by digital competitors.

Lastly:

> My prefix is known for its swamps and men,
> My suffix was mine, but I hadn't bonded then.

**What's happening?**

Hint:

> I wanted to add some more flavor,
>  But it would only make the riddle harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are:

> **baking a cake**! Specifically, a [pound cake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_cake), as you are creating a 'mix' (as per the title) of equal parts **BUTTER**, **SUGAR**, **EGG** and **FLOUR**.

*My prefix is something located behind,*
*My suffix a place I go with worry on my mind.*

> BUTT ('behind') + ER (Emergency Room - 'a place I go with worry...')

*My prefix is wind, albeit reversed and then headless,*
*My suffix noble, and helps to be soundless.*

> SUG (i.e. GUS(-t) reversed) + AR (Argon = Ar, a 'noble' gas, used in double-glazing for better heat insulation though often popularly thought to be used for [soundproofing](https://www.custom-windows.net/blog/noise-reduction/noise-reducing-windows-for-a-calm-house/#:%7E:text=Contrary%20to%20popular%20belief%2C%20argon,does%20nothing%20for%20sound%20reduction.))

*My prefix rises quickly, when adding numbers to its core,*
*My suffix a goodbye, used by digital competitors.*

> As solved by Rand al'Thor: E (the mathematical constant, *e*, representing exponential growth) + GG (gamer speak for goodbye)

*My prefix is known for its swamps and men,*
*My suffix was mine, but I hadn't bonded then.*

> FL (the abbreviation for Florida, known for the swamps of the Everglades and '[Florida Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florida_Man)' headline memes) + OUR (after partnering up, what *was* 'mine' becomes 'ours')

All of this explains the reference to 'flavor' in the hint also :)

Comment: Congrats! Here's a tad of clarification for some of the riddle rot13(Netba vf hfrq va jvaqbj fbhaqcebbsvat, gur jryy-xabja, "Sybevqn Zna" urnqyvarf. Nf sbe gur jubyr pnxr, vgf cbhaq pnxr!)

Comment: @Auribouros Aha, okay, will add a couple of those points for completeness... (although I had always understood it to be connected to heat-retention rather than soundproofing)

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: third one is

> EGG.

*My prefix rises quickly, when adding numbers to its core,*

> The mathematical constant $e$: the exponential function increases very fast.

*My suffix a goodbye, used by digital competitors.*

> GG, used by online game players.

The whole thing might be

> stages of animal development, e.g. if one of the other answers might be CHICK or LARVA or CHICKEN or ...